# redundant multiple implementations of one function in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using `scipy` to do some image processing job, and I found something quite confusing, that is some functions, say `scipy.signal.convolve`, `scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve`, have the same name and functionality, but they belong the different modules of `scipy`, so I kinda wonder why not just implement them once ?

Comment: One seems to take the `weight` argument and one doesn't. Are you sure they are the same? They seem different by reading the Docs.

Comment: @SukritKalra, well, they all does convolution, why not just make them one?

Answer (score 1):

They do slightly different things, mostly related with how they handle the convolution when the two arrays being convolved don't fully overlap.

[`scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html) always returns an array of the same size as its first parameter. To handle areas near the boundaries, where the second array may not fully overlap with the first, it makes up for those values using one of these options: `reflect`, `constant`, `nearest`, `mirror` or `wrap`.

[`scipy.signal.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) always pads the arrays with zeros as needed, and gives a return with three options, `full`, `valid` or `same`, which determine the size of the return array, depending on whether values calculated relying on the zero-padding are to be kept or discarded.

Comment: Yes, but personally I think `filters.convolve` might make use of `signal.convolve` to save the work of implementation.